# Execution time differences between time commands

Tags: find, time

To my understanding, the more commands I execute to get a desired output, the more the execution time is going to take.

Let's take this:

```
time find /opt/platforms/ -name '*trading*cfg' | xargs grep SenderCompID | awk -F= '{print $2};

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Which is a great execution time.

I beautify this ugly one-liner:

```
time find /opt/platforms/ -name '*trading*cfg' -exec grep SenderCompID {} \; | awk -F= '{print $2}'

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

And even though I reduced one pipe and used the `find -exec`, the time is a bit longer.

I take it even further and use only find, without any pipes:

```
time find /opt/platforms/ -name '*trading*cfg' -exec sed -n '/SenderCompID/s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/p' {} \;

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The "worse" result.

Let's say I'm in a mounted network device, this can be 10x in time, and the minor differences would be significant.

Can someone explain how the seemingly more efficient command takes the longest to execute?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "beautifying" made execution time worse. The program `xargs` will call `grep` with multiple files, while `-exec` will call `grep` for each file (you can verify this be replacing `grep` with `echo`). If `grep` can process multiple files during each call, it will be called fewer times (no startup required, no calling overhead). The same holds if you call `sed` instead of `grep`.